# how to close 'closing' sockets on linux use command?

Tags: linux, sockets

in my linux server, there are so many tcp connections at 'closing' state, netstat results like:

```
tcp        1     61 local-ip:3306         remote-ip:11654       CLOSING     -
```

How can I closed these connections?  The local process is restarted, so I can't find the pids.

And I have restart network, but unused.

I can't restart the server, because there are services running.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Relax, it won't cause any problems (unless there is a huge amount of these in which case it is a denial of service attack).

This will help understand what's going on: [TCP State transition diagram](http://www.night-ray.com/TCPIP_State_Transition_Diagram.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. After about 2 hours, these sockets have been closed auto.